# Customize Django Admin Add Form

Tags: python, django, model, admin

I'm stuck on Django, in fact, I would like to know how to customize a model's Admin add form and also process the information. I was able to modify the form from the **add_form_template** attribute of **ModelAdmin** but after nothing more, I also cannot use correctly **add_view**

here's code:

```py
# admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Schedule

@admin.register(Schedule)
class ScheduleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['doctor_name', 'date', 'timerange']
    list_display_links = ('doctor_name',)
    list_filter = ['date']

    add_form_template = 'admin/add_schedule.html'

    def add_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        return super().add_view(request)

    def doctor_name(self, schedule):
        return schedule.doctor.name

    doctor_name.short_description = "Medecin"
```

And add_schedule.html:

```html
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}

{% block title %}My title{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    My content and forms here.

{% endblock %}
```